# convert two inputs into monetary with two inputs

Tags: decimal, python-3.3

How do I change my inputs simple and compound with two decimals behind them?

```
n = 5
rate = 0.05
for n in range(0, 3):
    principal = 10000
    for n in range (0,6):
        principal <= 15000
        simple = principal *  (1 + rate * n)
        compound = principal * (1 + rate)**n
        ratea = rate * 100
        ratea = int(ratea)
        principal = int(principal)
        print((ratea),"% $",principal," $",simple," $",float(compound))
        principal = principal + 1000
    rate = rate + 0.05
```

Here when I run the program:

```
>>> 
5 % $ 10000  $ 10000.0  $ 10000.0

5 % $ 11000  $ 11550.0  $ 11550.0

5 % $ 12000  $ 13200.000000000002  $ 13230.0

5 % $ 13000  $ 14949.999999999998  $ 15049.125000000002

5 % $ 14000  $ 16800.0  $ 17017.0875

5 % $ 15000  $ 18750.0  $ 19144.223437500004

10 % $ 10000  $ 10000.0  $ 10000.0

10 % $ 11000  $ 12100.000000000002  $ 12100.000000000002

10 % $ 12000  $ 14400.0  $ 14520.000000000002

10 % $ 13000  $ 16900.0  $ 17303.000000000004

10 % $ 14000  $ 19600.0  $ 20497.400000000005

10 % $ 15000  $ 22500.0  $ 24157.65000000001

15 % $ 10000  $ 10000.0  $ 10000.0

15 % $ 11000  $ 12649.999999999998  $ 12649.999999999998

15 % $ 12000  $ 15600.0  $ 15869.999999999998

15 % $ 13000  $ 18850.000000000004  $ 19771.374999999996

15 % $ 14000  $ 22400.0  $ 24486.08749999999

15 % $ 15000  $ 26250.0  $ 30170.35781249999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `simple` with `"{:.2f}".format(simple)`, etc.  Here's [a good reference](https://mkaz.com/2012/10/10/python-string-format/).

Comment: would you know how to put this into cleaner rows and columns? i thought that would fix that as well but did not..thanks for the help!

Comment: @CharlesTaylor You can try setting the width to something larger than any number that you expect in each column (e.g. 10): `{:10.2f}".format(simple)`. You could also add a delimiter between your columns such as a comma, ampersand or vertical bar to make it easier to import to Excel, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a great time to use [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects). The [quick-start tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial) is a great place for an overview of the module. Just change your monetary values to `decimal.Decimal` objects, set the precision to two digits, and you'll be all set.